# My Program crashes when it reaches "cin << ans1 "

Tags: c++

This program literally crashes when it reaches `cin >> ans1;`.
I wrote this code in `atom` but I tried the same program in `code::blocks` and it works perfectly. Is there something wrong with my `atom` compiler...

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string name[30];
string gender;
int age;

void Job()
{
  printf("To apply for Job, Plz Enter your name: ");
  getline(cin, name[20]);
  printf("Enter Your Gender: ");
  cin >> gender;
  printf("Enter your age: ");
  cin >> age;
  printf("\n");

  while (age > 100)
  {
    printf("Enter a real age Dumbass: ");
    cin >> age;
  }

  return;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  Job();
  char ans1;

  printf("\n");
  printf("Entered Information is...\n");
  cout << "Name: " << name[20] << "       " << "Sex: " << gender << endl;
  cout << "Age: " << age;
  printf("Is this Correct?(y/n): ");
  cin >> ans1;

  if (ans1 == 'y')
  {
    if (age < 60 && age > 14 )
    {
      printf("It seems that you are eligible to vote...\n");
      printf("Go to our Website to Sign up...\n");   /* code */
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Sorry... But you are not Eligable to be hired...\n");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    while(ans1 != 'y')
    {
       printf("Write again...\n");
       Job();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin << ans1` isn't in the code, maybe `cin >> ans1`?

Comment: Works fine for me. What input are you having issues with? It's worth noting that `string name[30];` makes 30 strings, and then with code like `getline(cin, name[20]);` you're just working with string 20 out of those 30, while never doing anything with the other 29 strings.

Comment: not the problem, but you have an infinite loop where you have `while(ans1 != 'y')` because inside the loop `ans1` wont change. Also calling a person with age above 100 a "dumbass" is very disrespectful

Comment: What do you mean by "literally crashes"?        You may think it's obvious what it means, but it is one of those terms that different people may attach different meanings to.

Comment: Unrelated: Only accepting people <= 100 years old will make the program obsolete before you get that old.

Comment: btw atom and codeblocks are both IDEs. What IDE you use to edit your code is rather irrelevant for crashes. What can matter is the compiler, I would guess they are both using gcc

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: This program is running perfectly in codeblocks but it crashes when I compile it in atom.First in atom when I press F5 for compile and run it show the is Error: 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Job' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. But when I run by opening the .exe file it crashes on the "cin >> ans1 stage.

Comment: The problem that you can't run the program in Atom is a configuration problem and has nothing to do with C++. _"This program is running perfectly in codeblocks"_, I don't believe you. If you enter something different than 'y' in `cin >> ans1;` you will end in an infinite loop. _"But when I run by opening the .exe file it crashes on the "cin >> ans1 stage."_ What does this mean? How do you now where it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

first of all there's no meaning by putting `ans1 != y`in a while loop because `ans1` won't change and nothing new will happen try using this

```
#include <cstdio>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
using namespace std;

string name[30];
string gender;
int age;

void Job()
{
  printf("To apply for Job, Plz Enter your name: ");
  getline(cin, name[20]);
  printf("Enter Your Gender: ");
  cin >> gender;
  printf("Enter your age: ");
  cin >> age;
  printf("\n");

  while (age > 100)
  {
    printf("Enter a real age Dumbass: ");
    cin >> age;
  }

  return;
}

void h()
{
  Job();
  char ans1;

  printf("\n");
  printf("Entered Information is...\n");
  cout << "Name: " << name[20] << "       " << "Sex: " << gender << endl;
  cout << "Age: " << age;
  printf("Is this Correct?(y/n): ");
  cin >> ans1;

  if (ans1 == 'y')
  {
    if (age < 60 && age > 14 )
    {
      printf("It seems that you are eligible to vote...\n");
      printf("Go to our Website to Sign up...\n");   /* code */
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Sorry... But you are not Eligable to be hired...\n");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if(ans1 != 'y')
    {
       printf("Write again...\n");
       h();
    }
  }

}

int main()
{
    h();
}
```